# DevExpress Asp.net Control validation kicks in unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using latest DevEx Asp.net controls. In one of my pages, I have a form with AspxLabels and AspxTextBoxes. In certain textboxes I have a required field validation. I also have 2 check boxes on the page when clicked they populate certain textboxes with data from server.

Here is when the problem occurs.

When any of the check boxes are clicked, I make all textboxes that would be populated from server set to empty string. Then I set the data.

If one of the required fields already has some data, then setting it to empty string when checkbox is checked causes client side validation to kick in and server call to get the data is not done.

Does anyone have any idea how to approach and solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description (aspx would make it more clear) you should set [ValidationSettings.ValidateOnLeave](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsValidationSettings_ValidateOnLeavetopic) to false and validate editor manually.

Here is sample from devex code central article:

```
<input type="button" value="Validate" onclick="tbTextBox2.Validate();" />

<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbTextBox2" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="tbTextBox2">
    <ValidationSettings ValidateOnLeave="False">
        <RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="Field is required." />
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

For various ways of validating form editor(s) on client side read [How to raise validation on the client side](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E124.aspx).

Comment: Thanks very useful link. I apply and see if it works ,then I mark this as the answer